# XGBoost with R, nthread ignored?

Tags: r, xgboost

I know R itself is singlethreaded, but XGboost has a parameter nthread which supposedly should control the number of threads xgboost is using for processing. However, no matter how I set it, I see only one of my cores being used.

What needs to be done to make it run in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

Are you on a mac? The native C++ compiler (Clang) doesn't support openMP so you have to do some hacking to enable multi-threading.

https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/build.md